# afmotor saying "servo does not name a type"

Tags: servo

I have made a sumobot with an arduino, an afmotor shield and a 4-pin ping sensor when I upload my code it keeps giving me this error: "'Servo' does not name a type" here is my code.

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define TRIGGER_PIN  A0  // Arduino pin tied to trigger pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define ECHO_PIN     A2  // Arduino pin tied to echo pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200 // Maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-500cm.

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); // NewPing setup of pins and maximum distance.

 //speed variables for the left and right motor
int Lspeed = 180;
int Rspeed = 255;

//declaring the left and right motors and attaching them to 
//their corresponding connector on the motor shield
Servo leftMotor;
Servo rightMotor;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //sets initial speed
  leftMotor.setSpeed(Lspeed);
  rightMotor.setSpeed(Rspeed);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned int uS = sonar.ping(); // Send ping, get ping time in microseconds (uS).
  unsigned int CM = uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;
  
  if (CM &lt; 15 && CM &gt; 0) {
    int iteration = 0;
    while( iteration == 0){
      leftMotor.run(FORWARD);
      rightMotor.run(BACKWARD);
      iteration = 1;
    }
    delay(600);
  }
  
  //starts motors going forward
  leftMotor.run(FORWARD);
  rightMotor.run(FORWARD);
  
  Serial.print("Ping: ");
  Serial.print(uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM); // Convert ping time to distance in cm and print result (0 = outside set distance range)
  Serial.println("cm");
}
```

Comment: Try #include <Servo.h>

Comment: As a kindness to people reading your question and trying to answer please include your code in the question rather than linking to it. Also, including the code ensures that it will stay available.

Comment: ok, but the insert code thing kept glitching out and just showing garbled text in varying bold and code

Comment: also im using 2 paralax servos (large)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does it say "Servo" does not name a type](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-does-it-say-servo-does-not-name-a-type)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `Servo` objects instead of `AF_DCMotor` objects. Change this:

```
Servo leftMotor;
Servo rightMotor;
```

to this:

```
AF_DCMotor leftMotor(1);   // Change these numbers to the correct motor numbers
AF_DCMotor rightMotor(2);  // you are using on the shield
```